# How to use multiple if statements to color p tags

Tags: html, css, django

Im trying to color these four p tags based off of if they are either the correct answer or the one a user picked, there seems to be an error in the if statements however because it will only color it green or red, the loop doesnt go to color the red one for what the user picked and green for the correct answer

```
<p  {% if quiz.correctness1 == 0 and quiz.userAnswer1 == 'a' %}
        style="color:red"
    {% elif quiz.answer1 == 'a' %}
        style="color:green"
    {% endif %}>
    A. {{ quiz.q1Choice1 }}
</p>
<p  {% if quiz.correctness1 == 0 and quiz.userAnswer1 == 'b' %}
        style="color:red"
    {% elif quiz.answer1 == 'b' %}
        style="color:green"
    {% endif %}>
    B. {{ quiz.q1Choice2 }}
</p>
<p  {% if quiz.correctness1 == 0 and quiz.userAnswer1 == 'c' %}
        style="color:red"
    {% elif quiz.answer1 == 'c' %}
        style="color:green"
    {% endif %}>
    C. {{ quiz.q1Choice3 }}
</p>
<p  {% if quiz.correctness1 == 0 and quiz.userAnswer1 == 'd' %}
        style="color:red"
    {% elif quiz.answer1 == 'd' %}
        style="color:green"
    {% endif %}>
    D. {{ quiz.q1Choice4 }}
</p>
```

It will only color red if they are wrong and the if statements don't countinue to do
both red and green

**Model**

```
class QuizHistory(models.Model):
    userAnswer1 = models.TextField()
    answer1 = models.TextField()
    correctness1 = models.IntegerField()
    q1Choice1 = models.TextField()
    q1Choice2 = models.TextField()
    q1Choice3 = models.TextField()
    q1Choice4 = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this to:

```
<p {% if quiz.correctness1 == 0 and quiz.userAnswer1 == 'a' %}
     style="color:red"
   {% elif quiz.answer1 == 'a' %}
     style="color:green"
   {% endif %}>
   A. {{ quiz.q1Choice1 }}
</p>
<p {% if quiz.correctness1 == 0 and quiz.userAnswer1 == 'b' %}
     style="color:red"
   {% elif quiz.answer1 == 'b' %}
     style="color:green"
   {% endif %}>
   B. {{ quiz.q1Choice2 }}
</p>
```

you can covert strings to a lowercase variant with:

```
<p {% if quiz.correctness1 == 0 and quiz.userAnswer1.lower == 'a' %}
     style="color:red"
   {% elif quiz.answer1 == 'a' %}
     style="color:green"
   {% endif %}>
   A. {{ quiz.q1Choice1 }}
</p>
```

But I would strongly advise to do this in the models/views.

Comment: would you have any idea why that wouldn't work?

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: exactly what are the values of `correctness1`, `userAnswer1` and `answer1` in this case? Please provide some sample data with the expected outcome.

Comment: correctness1 returns either a 1 or a 0 depending on if the user got the answer correct on another page. userAnswer1 returns the letter value of the choice they picked 'a', 'b', 'c', or 'd'. answer1 returns the letter value of the correct answer 'a','b','c', or 'd'.    Lets say for example the user chose B but the answer is C, then correctness1 = 0, userAnswer1 = 'b', and answer1 = 'c'. What I would then like to happen is the p tag for the C choice to be green and the P tag for choice B be red

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: what is the current result? Note that for question `B` you need to change both the `userAnswer1` and the `quiz.answer1` checks.

Comment: I updated the code to include your updates and show all four options

Comment: currently if the user is correct then it colors nothing and if they are wrong it only colors their selection red

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: are you sure that if the user is correct, that `quiz.correctness1` is `1` (not `True`/`False`/`0`, etc.)?

Comment: yes in my Django program it is specifically created as a 1 integer

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: what do you see if you print `{{ quiz.correctness1 }}` somewhere before the `{% if ... %}` statements.

Comment: a 1 is displayed

Comment: @BrynnanWellman please show your _model_ and how this value is set there. `{{ quiz.correctness1 }}` renders the _string_ representation of that not it's _actual_ value.

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: if I run this with `'correctness1': 1`, `'userAnswer1': 'a'`, `'answer1': 'a'`, it displays it with a green style. So likely the data is slightly different.

Comment: I added the model at top, if I create the correctness1 field using a textfield from another model it would automatically switch to an integer, correct?

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: not if you do not save it to the database. If you simply make a `QuizHistory` object with `'1'`  as string, and you pass that to your model, then it is a string.

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: what happens if you check with `== '0'` instead?

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: see for example https://pastebin.com/110QK8Pk for a session to render this.

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: it renders it with green in the `'<p \n     style="color:green"\n   >\n   A. \n</p>'` template response.

Comment: @BrynnanWellman note you have a typo it is `UserAnswer1` not `userAnswer1` (capital vs small `u`), but this should be stopping you from getting a red colour (how do you get that?)

Comment: when I check with =='0' it no longer colors red either, therefore it is an integer field

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: aaarrggghhh... yes, that is likely the problem.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that error is not actually in my code, let me fix that

Comment: sadly guys...it is not :(

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: but in the pastebin I have given you a way to render it. Can you provide data for which you expect a different outcome, just by modifying the items in the `'quiz' : { ... }` dictionary?

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: just copy the dictionary as comment, or create a new pastebin.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the world does not deserve you, thank you for hanging in with me for so long

Comment: answer1 was not saving as 'a' or a letter but rather the longer string form of the choice its self such as "the answer is 3 red cars"

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: aha, so if you fix this, then it works properly?

Comment: but now doesn't work for another reason, I may just drop the feature

Comment: it is coloring the correct answer green, but the red doesn't display as well

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: I think it is better to fix the problem in your model/view. Even if you dismiss the feature of coloring answers, it still is not a good idea, since it will raise difficulties in for example determining the score, presenting the data in a CSV/JSON file, etc.

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: do you use `userAnswer1` or `UserAnswer1`. This should be consistent with the model and the template.

Comment: how do u use .lower() on the quiz.userAnswer1

Comment: @BrynnanWellman: you can work with `quiz.userAnswer1.lower == 'a'`, but I would advise that you convert it to lowercase in the view that *creates* the record, or make a property in the model, since normally templates should *not* be concerned with *business logic*.